# Safely pass user input to a CLI application on the server?

Tags: php, security

My code will, from a web-gui, generate [Vash](http://thevash.com) images. This currently involves making a call to a local binary, java. I'm wondering, if I've taken reasonable measures against this being exploited by a malicious user, or not.

The code will be used in several different places, by several different administrators, meaning both that I want to retain as much flexibility as reasonably possible, and that different users will have different opportunities to subvert the content of the `$arguments` variable.

From the code has been striped some **@todo** comments, and completely hard coded error messages.

There are three functions involved.

```
_vash_call_local_vash(array $arguments); // Responsible for building the command to be executed.
_vash_proc_open($cmd, $context); // Executes the command built above.
_vash_defaults() // Provides a set of default arguments.
```

`$base_dir` Will be supplied by a program that I don't have any control over. Should I be doing extra validation on the sanity of that variable?
At this point I don't know what the function will look like, that retrieves the exact path.

To avoid misuse, I mainly do two things. First, I hard code the parameter names, and then read only actual parameter values from keys in the hard coded list. I believe this will avoid the possibility of someone adding **extra** parameters. Second, I `escapeshellarg()` all the parameter values. I'm worrying a bit that it will be possible to somehow trick Java into executing the wrong jar file?

```
function _vash_call_local_vash($arguments) {
  if (empty($arguments['data'])) {
    return NULL;
  }
  elseif (empty($arguments['output'])) {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (isset($arguments['data'])) {
    $arguments += _vash_defaults();

    $base_dir = '/some/recieved/path/';

    // Collapse the arguments array into a single line.
    // Use hard-coded list of argument names to avoid the possibility of using
    // that as an attack vector.
    $names = array('format', 'width', 'height', 'algorithm', 'output', 'data');
    $cmd = 'java -jar ' . $vash_dir . 'Vash.jar ';
    foreach ($names as $name) {
      $cmd .= '--' . $name . ' ' . escapeshellarg($arguments[$name]) . ' ';
    }

    return _vash_proc_open($cmd);
  }
  return FALSE;
}

function _vash_proc_open($cmd, $context = NULL) {
  $descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w"),
  );
  $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, NULL, NULL, array('context' => $context));
  if (is_resource($process)) {
    $info = stream_get_meta_data($pipes[1]);
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], TRUE);
    stream_set_timeout($pipes[1], 1);
    $string = '';
    while (!feof($pipes[1]) && !$info['timed_out']) {
      $string .= fgets($pipes[1], 4096);
      $info = stream_get_meta_data($pipes[1]);
    };

    $info = stream_get_meta_data($pipes[2]);
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], TRUE);
    stream_set_timeout($pipes[2], 1);
    while (!feof($pipes[2]) && !$info['timed_out']) {
      $string .= fgets($pipes[2], 4096);
      $info = stream_get_meta_data($pipes[2]);
    };

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $code = proc_close($process);
    return array('cmd' => $cmd, 'output' => $string, 'code' => $code);
  }
  return FALSE;
}

function _vash_defaults() {
  $defaults = array(
    'format' => 'png',
    'width' => '512',
    'height' => '512',
    'algorithm' => '1.1',
    'output' => '/tmp/output.png',
    // 'salt-file' => 'salt-file',
  );
  return $defaults;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     }
```

Comment: are you running Java on the BackEnd or PHP?  the question is Tagged PHP but then you mention Java and Jar files?

Comment: @Malachi: If I read this correctly, it's PHP on the backend calling and external jar.

Comment: well it looks like a lot of fun..

Comment: @Malachi, it is correct as Bobby says. My code is PHP, and I need to call a jar. What exactly I'm calling is probably less interesting though, as the question should be applicable in any situation where php code executes shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

You aren’t validating any user input in your code, while `escapeshellarg` protects you from malicious arguments nothing protects you from calling your JAR with wrong arguments. Properly validating everything is the best advice I can give you.

**Example**

```
<?php

class Vash {

  protected $args;

  protected $path;

  public function __construct(array $args, $path) {
    if (!empty($args["data"]) && !empty($args["output"])) {
      $this->args = $args;
      $this
        ->validateFormat()
        ->validateDimension("width")
        ->validateDimension("height")
        ->validateAlgorithm()
        ->validateOutput()
        ->validateData()
        ->setPath($path)
        ->execute()
      ;
    }
  }

  protected function setPath($path) {
    if (!is_string($path)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException;
    }
    $path = "{$path}Vash.jar";
    if (!is_file($path)) {
      throw new LogicException;
    }
    $this->path = $path;
    return $this;
  }

  protected function validateFormat() {
    if (empty($this->args["format"])) {
      $this->args["format"] = "png";
    }
    else {
      switch ($this->args["format"]) {
        case "jpg":
        case "png":
          break;

        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException;
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }

  protected function validateDimension($dimension, $default = 512) {
    if (empty($this->args[$dimension])) {
      $this->args[$dimension] = $default;
    }
    elseif (filter_var((integer) $this->args[$dimension], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
      "flags"   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
      "options" => array( "min_range" => 10, "max_range" => 2000 ),
    )) === false) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  protected function validateAlgorithm() {
    if (empty($this->args["algorithm"])) {
      $this->args["algorithm"];
    }
    elseif (filter_var((float) $this->args["algorithm"], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array(
      "flags"   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
      "options" => array( "decimal" => 1 ),
    )) === false || $this->args["algorithm"] <= 0.0 || $this->args["algorithm"] > 1.0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  //
  // Continue with validation!
  //

  protected function execute() {
    $cmd = "java -jar {$this->path}";
    foreach (array("format", "width", "height", "algorithm", "output", "data") as $name) {
      $arg  = escapeshellarg($this->args[$name]);
      $cmd .= " --name '{$arg}'";
    }
    return _vash_proc_open($cmd);
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: This actually brings up a good point about the parameters that I haven't though off. Allowing arbitrary sizes has the potential to lead to a denial of service attack, since one could easily consume large amounts of disc space, processing power, and probably easily all available httpd connections. Despite that, I'm a bit hesitant to provide to rigorous checking on the other parameters, as I don't want this code to need updating should the underlying application add new options. I'll try to find a balance between the two. :)